# OS Error:[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save images after converting them into grayscale from one folder to another. when I run my code, it keeps saving the file in the same folder and making duplicates of all the images. Here is my code, Please guide where my problem lies...

```
import glob
import cv2
import os
spath=r"C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\*.png"
dpath=r"C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\grayscale images\*.png"
files = os.listdir(spath)
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\*.png'):
    print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(filename) 
    rl=cv2.resize(img, (40,50))
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rl, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dpath,filename), gray_image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a full pathname to glob.glob(), then it will return the full path of the result files, not just the filenames.

That means in this loop in your code:

```
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\*.png'):
```

filename is a full path such as `C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\myfile1.png`.

Then, later in the loop when you call `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dpath,filename), gray_image)`, you're trying to join together `C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\grayscale images\*.png` and `C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\myfile1.png`, which is the cause of your error.

`glob()` is convenient to get the full path of just the files you want, but then you have to separate the filename from the directory.

Try using `listdir()` instead of `glob()`:

```
import glob
import cv2
import os
sdir=r"C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza"
ddir=r"C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\grayscale images"
for filename in os.listdir(sdir):
    if not filename.lower().endswith(".png"):
        continue
    print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(sdir, filename))
    rl=cv2.resize(img, (40,50))
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rl, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(ddir,filename), gray_image)
```

Comment: Thank you @John Gordon... Can you explain me how can I remove this error so can I save images in other folder after convertion . Also I am new to Python so That's why I am getting confused....

Comment: Thank you sir for your help....But there seems to be a problem that when I run the code it gives syntax error on line 11 `  rl=cv2.resize(img, (40,50))` . When I remove this line or make it  comment it gives syntax error on next line 12. What will be the error Sir...@John Gordon

Comment: Whoops, the `imread` line had an extra opening parentheses.  I fixed it.